# Fill gaps of matrix that has irregular steps

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, matrix, increment

I am trying to perform a calculation using two different matrices, but they have come in slightly different forms.

The one matrix (for interests sake) are filled with reflectance values of a material from wavelengths 200nm to 2600nm, so each individual wavelength, in increments of 1 has a reflectance value.

The second matrix is a solar energy matrix which stores the amount of energy that is present at each wavelength. This one however has irregular steps and ranges from 280nm to 4000nm. But from 280nm-400nm it is in steps of 0.5nm, from 400nm-1705nm it is in steps of 1nm, and from 1750nm-4000nm it is steps of 5nm.

What I have been trying to do, unsucessfully thus far, is to edit this solar energy matrix so that it gives the entire range in steps of 1nm.

```
filename='H:\I_sol data.csv';
Dataisol = csvread(filename,1,0);

for j=1:1:count
   if Dataisol(j,:)~=Dataisol(j+1,:)-1 %compare the wavelength to the value of the next wavelegth   
       newx=(Dataisol(j,:)+[1,0])       %if the next wavelength is not 1 larger than the previous, add a new row 
       newx(1,2)=NaN                   %make the new row to add blank
       Dataisol=insertrows(Dataisol, newrow, j+1) %insert the new blank row
   end
end
```

Above is what I have started with, at the moment I am just trying to fill the gaps by adding in new rows where there is a 5nm jump between wavelengths. Once i am able to create the missing elements, then I will turn my attention to populating them with the correct values (probably the midpoint between the 2 given values)

My end goal is going to be to trim both of the matrices so that they both have the same starting and ending wavelength and both have increments of 1nm throughout (also for interest sake, or for advice if this is trivial for someone). If anyone knows how to fill these gaps or make the necessary changes to the matrix it would be a great help!

Example of the csv file:

```
Wvlgth nm   Etr W*m-2*nm-1
280.0   8.2000E-02
280.5   9.9000E-02
281.0   1.5000E-01
281.5   2.1200E-01
282.0   2.6700E-01
282.5   3.0300E-01
283.0   3.2500E-01
283.5   3.2300E-01
284.0   2.9900E-01
284.5   2.5024E-01
285.0   1.7589E-01
285.5   1.5500E-01
286.0   2.4200E-01
...     .....
428.0   1.6510E+00
429.0   1.5230E+00
430.0   1.2120E+00
431.0   1.0990E+00
432.0   1.8220E+00
433.0   1.6913E+00
434.0   1.5600E+00
435.0   1.7090E+00
436.0   1.8680E+00
437.0   1.9000E+00
438.0   1.6630E+00
439.0   1.6010E+00
440.0   1.8300E+00
....    .....
2205.0  8.0900E-02
2210.0  8.0810E-02
2215.0  8.0410E-02
2220.0  7.9990E-02
2225.0  7.8840E-02
2230.0  7.8400E-02
2235.0  7.7930E-02
2240.0  7.6510E-02
2245.0  7.6250E-02
2250.0  7.5370E-02
...      .....
```

---

Here is the code I use for assigning the variables to be used in the interp1 function, which is called as follows:

```
solx=Dataisol(:,1);
soly=Dataisol(:,2);
xi=280:1:2600;
newsol = [xi interp1(solx,soly,xi,'linear','extrap')];
```

The values that are stored in these variables as well as the error I am receiving are given below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need here is interp1. Set xi to be a vector of all the wavelengths you want to consider, say `xi=280:1:2600;`.

if `wavelength` is a vector of all your irregular values from the file, and `sol` is the corresponding vector of all the solar energies (you can use column references for your single matrix here as well)

`newsol = [xi interp1(wavelength,sol,xi,'linear','extrap')];`

will give you a new matrix with wavelengths increasing by 1 in column 1, and column 2 will contain values directly from your file where they exist and linearly interpolated values where they do not.

Comment: should the line with "newsol=..." be inserted on its own or within the for loop? I have tried to impliment it, but receiver the following error: (Error using griddedInterpolant. The grid vectors must contain unique points)

Comment: No loop required

Comment: I Still don't seem to be able to get it working, I have added some further info that shows what my variables look like, as well as the error I am getting

Comment: There were a bunch of zeros stored at the end of the matrix, so removing them solved the issue and allowed me to use interp1